# Could heat from a dryer vent damage the paint of a car?

Tags: paint, damage

Excessive heat can damage paint and loosen decals on a car. Automotive paint is extremely durable, designed to withstand a lot of punishment. However, like any substance, it has limits.

Let us say a house has a dryer that vents out the side of the house where the driveway is. A cursory search indicates dryers may output air as hot as 200°F (93.3°C).

If I were to park a car next to this vent for several days with multiple loads of laundry going through that dryer, with one of the body panels approximately one foot away from the vent, could that heat damage the paint?

If it does not damage the paint, could it discolor or otherwise make that portion of the paint appear different from the paint on the rest of the car?

Note: most vents are angled down to avoid water penetration. For the purpose of this question, assume the vent is damaged and the air is not deflected.

Comment: It may do? Is this what you have found...

Comment: 200 degrees at the exhaust vent of the dryer?  Are you sure about this temperature?  What heat does the dryer operate at?  I'd be more concerned with injury to someone physically walking past the vent than damage to a vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

If exhaust air is 100'C what is far away at point of contact. Is that more than black paint with solar heat of of 10 watts per  cm^2.

maybe or  probably not. At least it won't rust.

Comment: Where are you to get 10 watts / cm^2 ?? Based on an average of 1120 W/m^2 that is 0.112 W/cm^2. And the solar constant is taken as 1388W/m2 outside the atmosphere.